# Selecting parent elements with WebdriverJS

Tags: node.js, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to create some scripts which require moving through a lot of on-the-fly HTML with random IDs. They require getting the parents of an element - but I'm not sure how to implement this in WebdriverJS.

If I access the element I want via a console, I can do the following to get it;

```
document.querySelector('span[email="noreply@example.com"]').parentNode.parentNode
```

Is there a way to do this in WDJS? I've looked and can't see anything obvious - it's specifically the parent stuff I'm having issue with. I saw that a possible solution may be xPath however I'm unsure of syntax having never used it before.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the syntax of WebDriverJS. But the XPath is as below, you need a way to fit it in somewhere.

This is based on your CSS Selector, so please show HTML if needed.

```
.//span[@email='noreply@example.com']/../..
```

For example, if you have HTML like this

```
<div>
<div>
<span email="noreply@example.com">Contact me</span>
</div>
</div>
```

You can avoid using `..` to go up.

```
.//div[./div/span[@email='noreply@example.com']]
```

If you have more levels to look up, another handy method would be using `ancestor` from [XPath Axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp).
Also, as @sircapsalot brought up, CSS selectors spec doesn't support parent selecting, so XPath is the only way to go, unless you inject JS.

Comment: hopefully by CSS 4 they bring in a parent selector selector. they've been talking about something like `li! > a.active`  http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject

Comment: @sircapsalot: Yes, that would be really handy. Just not sure how long it's gonna take to finally release.

Comment: There is now way to select any parent elements in webdriverjs .. so using xPath is the right way to go

Comment: One thing to watch out for when using XPath selectors to match on a CSS class name with an element that has multiple classes, you need to match ALL classes you can't specify just one class like you can with CSS selectors. (i.e you need @class='k-widget k-combobox k-header mycustomclass"'] not just @class='mycustomclass']) - a workaround to not have to specify all classes is here: http://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/xpath-css-class-matching